# Error message "'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'"

Tags: python, attributes, int

```
import random

numbers = []
for i in range(301):
    numbers.append(random.randint(1,600))

g=0
u=0

for i in numbers:
    if i[-1]=="1" or i[-1]=="3" or i[-1]=="5" or i[-1]=="7" or i[-1]=="9":
        u +=1
    else:
        g +=1
print g
print u
```

it always gets me an error like this:

```
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I'm just a beginner, so I really don't understand, where's the problem here...so thank you for helping...

Comment: It would be nice to know what you're trying to do. Generally speaking the error is clear, you're trying to point to an index in an `int` (something like `1[0]`. `int` does not have indices.

Comment: I have a list of numbers, and I'm trying to count, how many of them are even numbers (g) and how many are uneven (u)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You let `i` be an element of `numbers`.  Elements of `numbers` are `int`s.  You cannot index integers:  `5[3]` ← makes no sense.

Indexing in Python is done via the method `__getitem__()`, so Python tries to call `5.__getitem__(3)` (which does not exist).  That's where the error message comes from.

What you probably wanted was stringifying the integers:

```
str(i)[-1]
```

to get the last digit of the number (as a character).

But since you compare with 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 I guess you want to test for being an odd number.  That is simpler done by:

```
i % 2 == 1
```